# How to pass a value to a subroutine in a different module?

Tags: python

I have the function `changecheck()` which is defined in a different module(called `check.py`). I want to pass `changeId` as a parameter to this function.

I am calling this function from the file `test.py`.

I am unable to understand the reason why this parameter is not being passed correctly.

```
check.py
returnVal = changecheck(changeInfoItem['changeId'])

In a differnt module test.py
def changecheck(changeId):
    print changeId //nothing gets printed
```

Comment: Why do you think this should work?

Comment: @Ignacio can you suggest a way to pass a value to a subroutine in a different module

Comment: You have not provided enough information to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem:

In the module test.py

```
def changecheck(changeId):
    print changeId
```

In the module check.py

```
import test
returnVal = test.changecheck(changeInfoItem['changeId'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to do this:

```
import check

returnVal = check.changecheck(changeInfoItem['changeId'])
```

Comment: @downvoter: please give me a reason. So I can correct the answer.

Comment: I was not the one to downvote you but I assume it has to do with the star import which is (rightfully) considered a bad practice.

Comment: @IcyFlame Normally anonymous downvoters pass along, downvote and never return back to the answer again, so it is (alas) pointless to ask them. Seen them often... :-/